# 20.04 windows network empty

Tags: networking, samba, ftp

Having upgraded to 20.04 the file manager shows the windows network as empty. In 19.10 I was able to open shares on my local server. On other computers in my network I am able to browse computers and workgroups. I suspect that this is a protocol/security issue as I can't connect to the server using ftp in the file manager either but I can connect with FileZilla. FileZilla does say that ftp over TLS is not available when I connect. How can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 2):

1. This a bug of samba:
   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1872476
2. The answer is:

add `client min protocol = NT1` into `/etc/samba/smb.conf` following `[global]`part

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sergiodj/samba-bug1872476-v2

sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks. this has fixed the problem :¬}

Comment: `The user named '~sergiodj' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/samba-bug1872476-v2'`